# Nexus 4 / Android tap to scroll issue

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, nexus-4

So I'm testing out a site on my Nexus 4, the layout when you browse to the page on mobile looks like so:

[image: Page layout]

It turns out on my phone, I can scroll or move the scroll bar down, by tapping the very edge of a screen. When I try to tap the right arrow, sometimes it will think that this is an attempt to scroll and move me down the page.

My question is, is this limited to the Nexus 4 device, Android or is it the Chrome Browser? I've tried it on both a HTC and even the Nexus 10 and it isn't possible so it seems to be localised to the Nexus 4 device. More importantly, is it possible to disable this?

Comment: I'm guessing that your tap is registering on the scrollbar instead of the arrow. On the other devices is there a larger space between the arrow and the scrollbar?

Comment: @Tanis.7x The scrollbar isn't visible on mobile devices. I just print screened with Desktop Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the scrollbar is not always visible in Chrome for Android, it is always present (when the page extends past the end of the screen) and will intercept touches on the edge of the screen.

As you scroll vertically on the Nexus, look for a gray bar on the right side. It is hidden when you are not scrolling, but it is still there and will still receive touches. The color of the scroll bar can also make it hard to see on certain backgrounds (such as the gray I see in your screenshot).

When I'm not touching the screen:

[image]

When I'm scrolling:

[image]